# State not correctly refreshed due to asynchronous calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in React (and in Javascript in general...) and I struggle to manage filters correctly. I think the problem comes from the fact that the calls are asynchronous but I cannot figured it out.

I have an application where you have matches and pronostics. You can filter matchs with a search box, as well as with a calendar:

- If I click on a day on the calendar, the list of match must be filtered, but not the calendar itself, otherwise I will not be able to click on any other day
- If I use the searchbox, both the matchs and the calendar must be updated

Both are OK in the fact that the matches are correctly filtered according to the day and/or search box, but it is not refreshed correctly, and the values of the pronostics and the score are completely messy after filtering

I have these 3 functions:

```
handleSelectDay = (selectedDate) => {
  this.setState({selectedDate},this.handleFilters)
}

handleSearch = (search) => {
  this.setState({search},this.handleFilters)
}

handleFilters = () => {
  console.log(this.state.selectedDate)
  const filteredMatchsWithoutDate = this.state.matchs
  .filter(match => {
    const valArray = this.state.search.toLowerCase().split(' ');
    let matchBool = true;
    for(let i = 0; i < valArray.length; i++) {
      if (
        match.team_a.name.toLowerCase().includes(valArray[i])
        || match.team_b.name.toLowerCase().includes(valArray[i])
        || match.location.toLowerCase().includes(valArray[i])
        || match.type.toLowerCase().includes(valArray[i])
      ){
        matchBool = true;
      }else{
        matchBool = false;
      }
    }
    return matchBool
  });
  const filteredMatchs = filteredMatchsWithoutDate
  .filter(match => {
    if(this.state.selectedDate != null)
      return isSameDay(parseISO(match.schedule),this.state.selectedDate)
    return true
  })
}
```

and my render function:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <main>
        <Navigation />
        <Container>
          <Filters
            onSearch={this.handleSearch}
            onCheckbox={this.handleCheckbox}
          />
          <Row>
            <Col sm={0} md={0} lg={4} xl={4} className="col-xxl-3">
              <Calendar 
                onSelectDay={this.handleSelectDay}
                matchs={this.state.filteredMatchsWithoutDate}
              />
            </Col>
            <Col sm={12} md={12} lg={8} xl={8} className="col-xxl-9">
              <Row>
                { this.state.filteredMatchs.map(match => <Match match={match} />) }
              </Row>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          </Container>

        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I think that the problem comes from `this.state.filteredMatchs.map(match => <Match match={match} />)` which is not correctly refreshed due to the state filter, but I cannot figure out how I could deal with it and the fact that handleSearch and handleCheckbox are already calling the handleFilters method ahead.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Looks like you forgot to update the state after filtering the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest fix would be adding a key which you can take from `map` function like:

```
this.state.filteredMatchs.map((match, index)=> <Match key={index} match={match} />)
```

So react knows that it has unique key and knows which one to use.
In real big application you shouldn't use `index` as a key. Key should be 100% unique so the best is to set it as ID or `uuid` etc.

Comment: It seems to be working if I use the ID of the match as key: `this.state.filteredMatchs.map((match)=> <Match key={match.id} match={match} />)`. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this could be because you are not using key props.

```
<Match key={someUniqueValue} match={match} />
```

Without key props react cannot track changes in arrays mapped to elements correctly.

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Edit/ PS. You should never use an array index to map these change and it defeats the purpose of key props - https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your state variable filteredMatchs in your handleFilters method. Your logic is there to filter the data but you are not updating the state. Adding the setState line at the end of your handleFilters method will make it work.

```
this.setState({filteredMatchs})
```

Also, as @jazz and @sowam suggested you should also add key attribute to your  component.